# How to assign default value to all NDB datastore entries?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have to add one new property to my existing NDB class:

```
class AppList(ndb.Model):
    ...
    ignore = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False) # new property
```

Then I will use it like below:

```
entries = AppList.query()
entries = entries.filter(AppList.counter > 5)
entries = entries.filter(AppList.ignore == False)
entries = entries.fetch()
```

I can not use `AppList.ignore != True` to catch early added records (which don't have `ignore` property), so I have to assign `False` for all records in my `AppList` entity. What is the most effective way to do it? Currently this entity contains about 4'000 entries.

**Upd**. I've decided to use the following ugly code (didn't manage to apply `cursors`), it runs as a cron job. But don't I update the same 100 records each time?

```
entities = AppList.query()
# entities = entities.filter(AppList.ignore != False)
entities = entities.fetch(100)
while entities:
    for entity in entities:
        entity.ignore = False
        entity.put()
    entities = AppList.query()
    # entities = entities.filter(AppList.ignore != False)
    entities = entities.fetch(100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget that there is a MapReduce library that is used in these cases. But I think the best method is to use all these suggestions toghether.

Now, you need to get() and put() 4000 entities and the question is how to reduce the "costs" of this operation.

I'm just curious to know what your `bool(entity.ignore)` returns. If a `missing` property return False you can adjust the code considering it False and postponed the operation. If you put() for other reason the property `ignore` is written to `False` thanks to the default argument. So, for the rest of the entities can run a script like this (via remote_api):

```
def iter_entities(cursor=None):
    entries = AppList.query()
    res, cur, more = entries.fetch_page(100, start_cursor=cursor)
    put_queue = [ent for ent in res if not hasattr(ent, 'ignore')]
    # put_queue = []
    # for ent in res:
    #    if not hasattr(ent, 'ignore'):
    #        put_queue.append(ent)
    ndb.put_multi(put_queue)
    if more:
        iter_entities(cur) # a taskqueue is better
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please clarify what the following line does: `put_queue = [ent for ent in res if not hasattr(ent, 'ignore')]`? If entry does not have 'ignore' attribute then what?

Comment: answer edited: ndb.get_multi() needs a list of entities. the line creates a list with inside only the entities that don't have 'ignore' property. it does the same thing of the 4 new lines.

Comment: Hmm. Do I understand it correctly - your code actually doesn't assign default value `False` to `ignore` property? I.e. one line is missing `ent.ignore = False` before `put_queue.append(ent)`?

Comment: put() or put_multi() set to the default argument every missing value. you need that line if you do not have the default parameter in the model.

Comment: That's strange then. Since I've run your code on my database, but it hasn't updated entries with this missing value... And, yes, I have `default=False` parameter in the model.

Comment: This means that your values is not `<missing>`, peraphs it's <null>?

Comment: I've just verified if `hasattr(ent, 'ignore')` returns correct value. And it is not - I've checked the entry which doesn't have `ignore` value and it returns `True`. Datastore viewer just doesn't show column `ignore`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40910/discussion-between-presveva-and-la)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using hasattr to check to see if a record has the ignore property.

If you just want to assign False for all records in your AppList entity, you just need to do an update to your schema (reload the models.py file) and then you should be able to set the property to False.

More information on a schema update can be found [here.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema)

EDIT:
to answer your comment:

```
if hasattr(entity, 'ignore'):
  #your code goes here
```

Comment: How can I use `hasattr` with `fetch`? See my updated question - the main question is how to fetch entities without this attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Your updated code will update first 100 entities only. try using cursor

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors

if u cant use cursor then use offset and keep increasing the offset by 100 on every loop or fetch all the entries once by fetch() (cursor approach is better one)

and instead of putting them one by one use
   ndb.put_multi(list of entities to put)

this will be more faster than putting one by one

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to use `cursors`, but I don't understand what should be `start_cursor` value when I call it second/third etc. time.

Comment: Each time you make a query using cursor, you'll get a set of data, and a cursor, until you reach the end of the data and you have no cursor (or cursor is None, I forget which).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way without deploying new code, will be to use the remote api and perform a query fetching all entities and setting the property value to false and and then put() them.  4000 records is not a lot.

In fact you don't even need to explicitly set the value, it will be set when retrieved to the default value if it has no value currently.

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like I have to set the value - see my question, if I use `query`, then it doesn't "apply" the default value.

Comment: Oh well it is just a simple for loop over the result set, set the value and put.