# hasattr returns always True for app engine ndb entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, hasattr

I am applying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19869907/492258) to my project

This is my ndb entity where is_deleted added later.

```
class FRoom(ndb.Model):  
    location = ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    is_deleted = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False) #added later 
    #other fileds
```

when I do print my entities with logging.info, I have

```
FRoom(key=Key('FRoom', 5606822106890240), is_deleted=False, location=u'denizli')
FRoom(key=Key('FRoom', 6169772060311552), is_deleted=False, location=u'aydin' )
FRoom(key=Key('FRoom', 6451247037022208), location=u'bursa')
```

When I do for do

```
for froom in frooms:
    logging.info(hasattr(froom, 'is_deleted')) # gives always True
```

but when I do for example:

```
logging.info(hasattr(froom, 'is_deletedXXX')) #gives me False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Question: why isn't `is_deleted` set in `FRoom(key=Key('FRoom', 6451247037022208), location=u'bursa')` even though your default is set as `False`?

Comment: It is for soft delete control, to get  `cls.query(cls.is_deleted == False)` result

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour due to the `is_deleted` property having the `default` option set: the datastore will automatically return that default value if the property was not explicitly set.

From the [Property Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#options) table:

[image]

So for properties for which you set the `default` option in the model the check if the property exists is unnecessary - it always exists, so you can directly do:

```
for froom in frooms:
    logging.info(froom.is_deleted)
    # or
    logging.info(getattr(froom, 'is_deleted'))
```

The `hasattr(froom, 'is_deletedXXX')` returns False because you don't have a `is_deletedXXX` property in `FRoom`'s model.

Comment: I gave a try this but same result, I think `default` here is valid while inserting value

Comment: By the way if add `is_deletedXXX = ndb.BooleanProperty()` to model it gives me `True` as well, I work at localhost

Comment: Did you set `is_deletedXXX` when you created the entity? If so yes, you'll get True, if you don't set it you'll get False (assuming, of course, you didn't set the `default` option for `is_deletedXXX`).

Comment: I didn't even create entity, just update model and check if it is the case... bizarre

Comment: Existing entities are not automatically updated when you update the model. Check the actual entity content in the Datastore Viewer on the admin server page.